# Copy hex colour to clipboard using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to copy the background hex colour using JS. Is there a way to do this? I know there is `.execCommand("copy");` but for some reason it's not working. Not sure what I am missing here:

```
var color = '';

$('.copy-button').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    hexc(x);
    alert(color);
})

function hexc(colorVal) {
    var parts = colorVal.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

This is what I tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/DCaQb/997/

Comment: you haven't add jquery

Comment: You can't access `pseudo` elements from JS as it is not part of DOM

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bvcq2jz3/1/  if you want to copy only 1 will be copied . whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: @mahi you fiddle not work perfect . copy text with '#eee' is not copied

Comment: Javascript has no access to pseudoelements, they aren't part of the DOM

Comment: Hey guys, I am almost there. I found an alternative to copy the background colour instead. What I want to do is copy the hex value of the background. Not sure what I am missing here: http://jsfiddle.net/DCaQb/996/